# Calculus notation: is $\frac{dy}{dx}$ the same as $y'$ if $y\not = y(x)$?

Tags: calculus, notation

Suppose $y=y(ax)$ for some $a\in \mathbb{R}$. Would I correct in stating that $\frac{dy}{dx}\not =y'(ax)$ but rather the following is true:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=ay'(ax)=y'(x)?$$
Hence $\frac{dy}{dx}=y'(x)$ is still true as long as we say the argument for $y'$ is still in $x$?

Comment: What do you mean by $y=y(ax)$? Is this for a specific $x$, for all $x$, or what? Presumably by $y$ you mean the same function in both cases?

Comment: Off-topic.. but no question is 'stupid'. If it adds to your knowledge, then it definitely isn't stupid :)

Comment: @Jam Sorry, I meant as in say you already had an established function $y=y(x)$ but now you are considering $y=y(ax)$ instead, if that makes sense?

Comment: @JustWandering It does but that would be a bad way to notate it. In math (unlike programming), $=$ is a relation to say that two things are equivalent (not that something is becoming another thing). If you are defining a new term as $y(ax)$ you should give it a new name (e.g., $z(x)$ or $g(x)$, etc.). I think this is also the origin of your confusion: $y$ cannot be two functions, both $y(x)$ and $y(ax)$ at the same time.

Comment: @Jam. Thank you! Just as a double check, say I define $\phi (x) = y(ax)$ then is it correct, and notationally sound, that $\phi'(x)=ay'(ax)$

Comment: Yeah, that's correct.

Comment: When treating this kind of problem, one should go back to the definition of a function: a set of pairs of elements $(x,y)$, $x$ from a set $A$ and $y$ from a set $B$ (which may be the same set) such that for each $x$ there is only one $y$. To emphasize this relation, we sometimes write $y$ as $y(x)$